# How to get console integer input from user in a dart program?

Tags: dart

I want to get integer input from console in dart but unable to do so . How do I do that?

```
    main()
{
    int n = stdin.readLineSync();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to parse string captured by `stdin.readLineSync()` using `int.parse()`

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
    int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
}
```