# how do parse in dart 2.12.0?

Tags: dart

i just update my dart-sdk to 2.12.0 then error happen

```dart
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  var waktuNow = DateTime.now();
  var waktuSekarang = waktuNow.year;
  stdout.write('Masukkan tahun kelahiran kamu : ');
  var tahunLahir = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  hitungTahun(waktuSekarang, tahunLahir);
}

void hitungTahun(int a, int b) {
  var lahir = a - b;
  print('umur kamu : $lahir ');
}
```

error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [myapps] bin\coba2.dart:6)

how input int in dart 2.12.0 ?

Comment: I will recommend you to read about the null safety feature introduced in Dart 2.12. You can start here: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798782/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-stri)

Comment: thanks @PatrickO'Hara, is there a way of inputting an int/number than use readlinesnyc in dart ? im new in dart

Comment: Not that I know of, use `readLineSync` ans `tryParse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are now using null safety in Dart. You now need to be explicit in what variables can be null and also ensure those potentially nullable variables are "null checked"

`stdin.readLineSync()` can potentially return a [null value](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html). So you need to check for this case.

```
var s = stdin.readLineSync();
if(s != null) {
  var tahunLahir = int.parse(s);
  hitungTahun(waktuSekarang, tahunLahir);
}
```

You should also be careful of `int.parse` as this can through errors. If you're not 100% sure that you'll always get a "parsable" int. Use [`int.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/int/parse.html) which also can return null. So further checks are required.

Comment: ahh, thank you so much, is there way of inputting an int other than use readlinesync? 
like using age = data.nextInt; in java

Comment: From looking around it doesn't look like that's an option, sadly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007696/how-to-get-console-integer-input-from-user-in-a-dart-program/55008738

Comment: so, the only way inputting data in dart is use readlinesync ? im new in dart